# whats is the expression in SSIS to get the same dates as in source to destination table

Tags: ssis

What is the expression in SSIS to get the same dates as in source to destination. If I am using GETDATE() it will give current date but I want the same dates mentioned in source.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to have the same date value for each row as it moves from the Source to the Destination.  You can create your own variable and add it as a Derived Column transformation to the dataflow or you can use a system variable like ContainerStartTime from an Audit transformation (or Derived Column, too).

[Here's an article on all the available System Variables in SSIS.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141788.aspx)

Since your wording was "same dates mentioned in source", you could do the following to get a single date from the source and use it in your data flow.

1. On the control flow, create a SQL task that returns `GETDATE()` as a single row result set from the source server.  Save this result to a variable.
2. Within a data flow, add a derived column transformation after the source.  Add the new variable value to the flow as a new column.
3. Map it to the destination column for a single date/time value that was derived from the source system right before the operation began.